# Is it possible to set na.rm to TRUE globally?

Tags: r, na, na.rm

For commands like `max` the option `na.rm` is set by default to `FALSE`. I understand why this is a good idea in general, but I'd like to turn it off reversibly for a while -- i.e. during a session.

How can I require R to set `na.rm = TRUE` whenever it is an option? I found

```
options(na.action = na.omit)
```

but this doesn't work. I know that I can set a `na.rm=TRUE` option for each and every function I write.

```
my.max <- function(x) {max(x, na.rm=TRUE)}
```

But that's not what I am looking for. I'm wondering if there's something I could do more globally/universally instead of doing it for each function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer you don't want is the only one that works generally. There's no global option for this like there is for `na.action`, which only affects modeling functions like `lm`, `glm`, etc (and even there, it isn't guaranteed to work in all cases).

Comment: @HongOoi - I think in light of the large number of upvotes on your comment it should be rehashed as an answer (or "the" answer potentially).

Comment: An alternative to have a fine control of where/when to omit NAs could be to include a variable such as `do.omit.na = TRUE` at the begining of your script, and to use it thereafter when applicable with `max(x, na.rm = do.omit.na)`.

Comment: anyone care to elaborate on why it's a good idea to set `na.rm=F` in general? Just as a way to flag to yourself that the `sum`/`mean`/etc that you calculate may not be exactly what you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to change `na.rm` to `TRUE` globally. (See Hong Ooi's comment under the question.)

**EDIT:**

> Unfortunately, the answer you don't want is the only one that works
>   generally. There's no global option for this like there is for
>   na.action, which only affects modeling functions like lm, glm, etc
>   (and even there, it isn't guaranteed to work in all cases). –  Hong
>   Ooi Jul 2 '13 at 6:23

Answer (score 12):

One workaround (dangerous), is to do the following :

1. List all functions that have `na.rm` as argument. Here I limited my search to the base package.
2. Fetch each function and add this line at the beginning of its body: `na.rm = TRUE`
3. Assign the function back to the base package.

So first I store in a list (ll) all functions having `na.rm` as argument:

```
uses_arg <- function(x,arg) 
  is.function(fx <- get(x)) && 
  arg %in% names(formals(fx))
basevals <- ls(pos="package:base")      
na.rm.f <- basevals[sapply(basevals,uses_arg,'na.rm')]
```

**EDIT** better method to get all na.rm's argument functions (thanks to mnel comment)

```
Funs <- Filter(is.function,sapply(ls(baseenv()),get,baseenv()))
na.rm.f <- names(Filter(function(x) any(names(formals(args(x)))%in% 'na.rm'),Funs))
```

So `na.rm.f` list looks like:

```
 [1] "all"                     "any"                     "colMeans"                "colSums"                
 [5] "is.unsorted"             "max"                     "mean.default"            "min"                    
 [9] "pmax"                    "pmax.int"                "pmin"                    "pmin.int"               
[13] "prod"                    "range"                   "range.default"           "rowMeans"               
[17] "rowsum.data.frame"       "rowsum.default"          "rowSums"                 "sum"                    
[21] "Summary.data.frame"      "Summary.Date"            "Summary.difftime"        "Summary.factor"         
[25] "Summary.numeric_version" "Summary.ordered"         "Summary.POSIXct"         "Summary.POSIXlt"
```

Then for each function I change the body, the code is inspired from `data.table` package (FAQ 2.23) that add one line to the start of `rbind.data.frame` and `cbind.data.frame`.

```
ll <- lapply(na.rm.f,function(x)
  {
  tt <- get(x)
  ss = body(tt)
  if (class(ss)!="{") ss = as.call(c(as.name("{"), ss))
  if(length(ss) < 2) print(x)
  else{
    if (!length(grep("na.rm = TRUE",ss[[2]],fixed=TRUE))) {
      ss = ss[c(1,NA,2:length(ss))]
      ss[[2]] = parse(text="na.rm = TRUE")[[1]]
      body(tt)=ss
      (unlockBinding)(x,baseenv())
      assign(x,tt,envir=asNamespace("base"),inherits=FALSE)
      lockBinding(x,baseenv())
      }
    }
  })
```

No if you check , the first line of each function of our list :

```
unique(lapply(na.rm.f,function(x) body(get(x))[[2]]))
[[1]]
na.rm = TRUE
```

Comment: `Funs <- Filter(is.function,sapply(ls(baseenv()),get,baseenv()));
na.rm.f <- names(Filter(function(x) any(names(formals(args(x)))%in% 'na.rm'),Funs))` will collect `min` and `max` ....

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I think I understand what you're doing, but I can't upvote or accept because the latest answer gives `Error in ss[[2]] : subscript out of bounds` and the first answer gives `max(5, NA) = NA`.

Comment: @Hugh I edit my answer. Now you don't have an error. But, unfortunately the code don't work for `primitive` functions that have `na.rm` argument: `"all"   "any"   "max"   "min"   "prod"  "range" "sum" `

Comment: or you could combine this with `setDefaults` from the `Defaults` package

Comment: @Ben `Package ‘Defaults’ was removed from the CRAN repository (...)  at the request of the maintainer, who had not updated it for R 3.1.0.` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/index.html

Answer (score 8):

For my R package, I overwrote the existing functions `mean` and `sum`. Thanks to the great Ben (comments below), I altered my functions to this:

```
mean <- function(x, ..., na.rm = TRUE) {
  base::mean(x, ..., na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

After this, `mean(c(2, NA, 3)) = 2.5` instead of `NA`.

And for `sum`:

```
sum <- function(x, ..., na.rm = TRUE) {
  base::sum(x, ..., na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

This will yield `sum(c(2, NA, 3)) = 5` instead of `NA`.

`sum(c(2, NA, 3, NaN))` also works.

---

You could also make it a global option:

```
sum <- function(x, ..., na.rm = getOption("na.rm", default = TRUE)) {
  base::sum(x, ..., na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

Now you can set the default value with `options()`, e.g. `options(na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: maybe slightly better to use `base::mean(...)` rather than `mean.default(...)` (in case you decide to take the mean of something that has a method other than the default).

Comment: Thanks! Put me on another idea :) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Why does this not appear to work when aggregating within a data.table? Eg, `dt[,.(x=mean(x)), by=Group]`?

Comment: Then it seems data.table implemented their own mean function that is called internally to increase speed, since it's such a common function? Not sure.

Answer (score 4):

There were several answers about changing `na.rm` argument globally already. I just want to notice about `partial()` function from `purrr` or `pryr` packages. Using this function you can create a copy of existing function **with predefined arguments**:

```
library(purrr)
.mean <- partial(mean, na.rm = TRUE)

# Create sample vector
df <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 6, 7)

mean(df)
>[1] NA

.mean(df)
>[1] 3.833333
```

We can combine this tip with @agstudy answer and create copies of all functions with `na.rm = TRUE` argument:

```
library(purrr)

# Create a vector of function names https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423072/9300556
Funs <- Filter(is.function,sapply(ls(baseenv()),get,baseenv()))
na.rm.f <- names(Filter(function(x) any(names(formals(args(x)))%in% 'na.rm'),Funs))

# Create strings. Dot "." is optional
fs <- lapply(na.rm.f,
             function(x) paste0(".", x, "=partial(", x ,", na.rm = T)"))

eval(parse(text = fs))
```

So now, there are `.all`, `.min`, `.max`, etc. in our `.GlobalEnv`. You can run them:

```
.min(df)
> [1] 1
.max(df)
> [1] 7
.all(df)
> [1] TRUE
```

To overwrite functions, just remove dot "." from lapply call. 
Inspired by [this blogpost](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/hijacking-r-functions-changing-default-arguments-3/)