# Saving na.rm=TRUE for each function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na.rm

I am using dplyr summarise function. My data contain NAs so I need to include na.rm=TRUE for each call. for example:

```
group <- rep(c('a', 'b'), 3)
value <- c(1:4, NA, NA)
df = data.frame(group, value)

library(dplyr)
group_by(df, group) %>% summarise(

          mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),

          sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE),

          min = min(value, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Is there a way to write the argument na.rm=TRUE only one time, and not
on each row?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418640/is-it-possible-to-set-na-rm-to-true-globally

Comment: You can use `na.omit`: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% na.omit() %>% summarise()`

Comment: na.omit() will delete the entire row with al least one NA. I don't want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `summarise_at`, which lets you compute multiple functions for the supplied columns and set arguments that are shared among them:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at("value", 
               funs(mean = mean, sd = sd, min = min), 
               na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: now that across() is the preferred approach in dplyr 1.0.0, how would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to apply your functions to one column only, you can use `filter(!is.na())` in order to filter out any `NA` values of this variable only (i.e. `NA` in other variables won't affect the process).

```
group <- rep(c('a', 'b'), 3)
value <- c(1:4, NA, NA)
df = data.frame(group, value)

library(dplyr)

group_by(df, group) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value),
            min = min(value))

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#    group  mean       sd   min
#   <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      a     2 1.414214     1
# 2      b     3 1.414214     2
```