# R making 'na.rm=TRUE' the default in statistics functions

Tags: r

Is there an R library package that defaults the na.rm argument in the basic descriptive statistics (mean, sd, etc.) to TRUE?  I want to have the option to set `na.rm=FALSE`, but I do not want this to be the default.

It is similar to [Is it possible to set na.rm to TRUE globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418640/is-it-possible-to-set-na-rm-to-true-globally) , but this has become dated and incomplete.  And, perhaps most importantly, it does not have a solution for sd, var, etc.

It's even trickier than that.  The following works EXCEPT it cannot be stuck into an .Rprofile file (where it states `Error: object 'var' not found`)

```
orig.var <- var
var <- function(x, ..., na.rm = TRUE) { orig.var(x, ..., na.rm = na.rm) }
```

Comment: This behavior is similar in concept to using `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` for `read.csv` and friends: it works well for the local user but has the potential to making your functions/scripts/packages non-reproducible. I also argue that making it the default is a statistical decision that may impact a lot more than you intend.

Comment: the answer can be inferred from the near-duplicate: "not possible."  There are ways to set all functions to `na.rm=TRUE`, but this no longer allows the user to specify `na.rm=FALSE` when so desired.  r2evans: agreed---this should not happen without a specific invokation.  it should have been a package that is on cran, so that code remains reproducible.